# User interface Scripting Issue Rigify Multiple Rigs Appended

Tags: scripting, interface, rigify

So I have created two characters in two separate blender documents. I used rigify to create a rig for both of them. I then appended both characters into the same blender document. The first character appended worked properly. [image: This image shows user interface complete] The user interface for rigify was complete with all of the animation tools built into rigify. Then I appended the second character. [image: This image shows missing rigify user interface] The user interface script didn't work properly as the controls for the tools built into rigify were missing. How do I bring in multiple characters and have each of them have their user interface intact? There is a rig_ui.py script that was appended with each character. It seems the script runs once for the first character, then on the second append the script can't handle a second rig. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I asked this same question on blender artist and got an answer that worked. Here is the link to that forum thread. [Blender Artists Forum Solution](https://blenderartists.org/t/user-interface-scripting-issue-rigify-muultiple-rigs-appended/1231957)